# TypeError: historyService.getHistory(...).success is not a function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

As you can see I'm trying to get the order history and inject it into my view but I get the error

> TypeError: historyService.getHistory(...).success is not a function

No Idea what is the issue but whenever I remove the code bellow from my controller it works fine, it is also worth mentioning that I get the content of nav.service and order history.service in console.

```
historyService.getHistory()
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config){
            vm.historyItems = data;
        });
```

History.Controller:

```
    (function () {
            'use strict';

            angular
                .module('app')
                .controller('HistoryController', HistoryController);

            HistoryController.$inject = ['navigationService','historyService', '$scope', '$timeout', 'ionicMaterialInk', 'ionicMaterialMotion'];
            function HistoryController(navigationService, historyService, $scope, $timeout, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion) {
                // Set Header
                $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.showHeader();
                $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.clearFabs();
                $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.setExpanded(false);
                $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.setHeaderFab(false);


                // Delay expansion
                $timeout(function () {

                    ionicMaterialMotion.slideUp({
                        selector: '.slide-up'
                    });

                }, 300);

                var vm = this;
                vm.menuItems = [];
                vm.historyItems = [];

                navigationService.getAllNavigations()
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config){
                    vm.menuItems = data;
                    $timeout(function () {
                        // Set Motion
                        ionicMaterialMotion.fadeSlideInRight();

                        // Set Ink

                        ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
                    }, 100);
                });

                historyService.getHistory()
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config){
                    vm.historyItems = data;
                });



            };
        })();
```

History.Service:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .service('historyService', historyService);

    historyService.$inject = ['$http', 'restServer', '$q'];
    function historyService($http, restServer, $q) {
        var historyService = {
            getHistory: getHistory
        };

        return historyService;

        function getHistory(OrderId) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if (OrderId != undefined)
                //Order ID exist
                $http.get(restServer + '/order_history/' + OrderId)
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log('getHistory(' + OrderId + ')');
                        console.log(data);

                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log('getHistory(' + OrderId + ') error');
                        console.log(data);

                    });
            else
                $http.get(restServer + '/order_history/')
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log('getHistory: ');
                        console.log(data);
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log('getHistory error');
                        console.log(data);
                    });

            return deferred.promise;
        }

    };
})();
```

Comment: Could you build a working plunker reproducing the error?

Comment: I knew little of angular; and there is a lot of files. I really can't

Answer (score 1):

Check the [docs for the $q Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api), these are the available methods on a promise object:

- `then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)`
- `catch(errorCallback)`
- `finally(callback, notifyCallback)`

The one you need is `then`.

`success` is only useable on `$http` promises and it is deprecated and should be replaced with the standard `then` method. See [Deprecation Notice in $http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice).

Edit: That will probably fix that error but you are missing some more code in the service. You should either return the promise object returned by the `$http.get()` call directly, or else you need to call `deferred.resolve()` at some stage so the promise will complete 
e.g.

```
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
})
```

Comment: Thanks I had no idea; I Will modify the code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In History.Service before

```
$http.get(restServer + '/order_history/')
```

I forgot to add return:

```
return $http.get(restServer + '/order_history/')
```